# Regarding Module Not Found Error: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am using pycharm and python3.10 and I have installed PyQt5 When using this snippet

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebPage
```

I got an error:
`from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets`
what should I do now and tried uninstalling it and reinstalling option but it didn't work so if I could have some help then it will be grateful to me, please.

Comment: Your question title doesn't match a valid import statement or error based on the code you are showing. Please provide the ***actual*** traceback. Besides, QWebPage has been deprecated **for years**, since the release of the QtWebEngine module for Qt 5.4 (using QWebEnginePage since then), which happened ***8 (eight!) years ago***.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebPage`.  `QWebPage` does not exist in the `QtWebEngineWidgets` module.  Here are the classes that do exist:

```py
    > CLASSES
    >     PyQt5.QtCore.QObject(sip.wrapper)
    >         QWebEngineDownloadItem
    >         QWebEnginePage
    >         QWebEngineProfile
    >     PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget(PyQt5.QtCore.QObject, PyQt5.QtGui.QPaintDevice)
    >         QWebEngineView
    >     sip.simplewrapper(builtins.object)
    >         QWebEngineCertificateError
    >         QWebEngineContextMenuData
    >         QWebEngineFullScreenRequest
    >         QWebEngineHistory
    >         QWebEngineHistoryItem
    >         QWebEngineScript
    >         QWebEngineScriptCollection
    >         QWebEngineSettings
```

Perhaps you intended to use `QWebEnginePage`?  `from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage` does work.

Comment: While the observation about QWebEnginePage instead of QWebPage is correct, that's not the actual issue. If that was the case, the error would have been `cannot import name 'QWebPage'`. The issue is before that, since it says that the *module* cannot be found.

Comment: @musicamante, when I ran the code in the post `from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebPage` I get the error `cannot import name 'QWebPage'`.  The post may have been edited, but I'm not seeing the `module cannot be found` issue at this time.

Comment: The point is not what you got, but what the OP did. The (original and unedited) title is clear: "Module Not Found Error: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'"

Comment: Good call, @musicamante.  I missed that.  Not sure about that since I'm not able to replicate the error.  I suspect that the error message being reported in the title is not the error message obtained from running the code shared in the post.  Some other code must have been executed to get the error in the title.

Comment: I don't know if the behavior has changed in versions of Python than the (quite old) one I'm using right now, but the `No module named` error is normally returned when the *base* module is not found. So, either the OP didn't properly write the question (as the issue would be about `PyQt5`, not `PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets`), or the issue is somewhere else. I'm voting to close this post as unreproducible.